# MongoDB connector for Django

Tags: django, mongodb

I could not find any standard database connector provided by Django for MongoDB. It seems that we have to use some third-party application/work around to do that.

Is there any specific reason for this absence?

Comment: Because Django is built for relational dbs.

Comment: Yeah, right! But should there not be a way to incorporate a NoSQL database too? They are convenient in many scenarios.

Comment: Yes, and that is why third-party libraries like Djongo exist.